# How to convert char array into string for DateTime.Parse?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, datetime, formatexception

I am using this in my controller:

```
char[] arrDate = date.ToArray();
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(arrDate[0] + arrDate[1] + "/" +
                             arrDate[2] + arrDate[3] + "/" +
                             arrDate[4] + arrDate[5] + arrDate[6] + arrDate[7]);
```

The error:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: How about [`date.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Please see if you can accept/upvote the answer. @yashu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
var date = "11252017";
var arrDate = date.ToArray();
var strDate = arrDate[0] + arrDate[1] + "/" +
              arrDate[2] + arrDate[3] + "/" +
              arrDate[4] + arrDate[5] + arrDate[6] + arrDate[7]; // 98/25/2017
```

Notice that:

- `'1' + '1' = 98`* ⇒ `char` + `char` = `int`
- `98 + "/" = "98/"` ⇒ `int` + `string` = `string`
- `"98/" + '2' = "98/2"` ⇒ `string` + `char` = `string`

The fix:

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("" +
                        arrDate[0] + arrDate[1] + "/" +
                        arrDate[2] + arrDate[3] + "/" +
                        arrDate[4] + arrDate[5] + arrDate[6] + arrDate[7]);
```

*[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) representation:

- `'1'` in decimal is `49`

Comment: Thanx my issue is fixed...Its working very good.

Comment: arrdate=date = "11202017";dt = {11/20/2017 12:00:00 AM} this is my output.

Comment: yes it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `date` is of type `string`. For parsing a string the `DateTime` class has several methods of which `ParseExact` is one. This method can parse a string given a format specifier and a culture. In your case the date can be parsed like this:

```
var date = "11252017";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

By the way a `string` is an array of `char`s, so in your code `arrDate[0]` is exactly the same as `date[0]`. Just something to keep in mind for the future.