# Elegant way to convert yyyyyMMddHHmmssffff string into acceptable value for DateTime.Parse?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have "202006260718083370" as an input value and I need to convert it into parse*-able* string for DateTime.Parse. Any elegant way that you can think of aside from the approach below?

**Approach 1** - Individually insert string in between.

```
var input = "202006260718083370".Insert(5, "-")
                                .Insert(8, "-")
                                .Insert(11, " ")
                                .Insert(14, ":")
                                .Insert(17, ":")
                                .Insert(20, ".");

var dateTime  = DateTime.Parse("2020-06-26 07:18:08.3370") // What input looks like
```

**Approach 2** - individually pass in new DateTime(....)

```
var year = "202006260718083370".Substring(0, 4);
var month = "202006260718083370".Substring(4, 2);
var date = "202006260718083370".Substring(6, 2);
var hour = "202006260718083370".Substring(8, 2);
var min = "202006260718083370".Substring(10, 2);
var sec = "202006260718083370".Substring(12, 2);
var mil = "202006260718083370".Substring(14, 4);
```

**Approach 3** - almost the same in approach 2. Use string array and concat. Like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482591/how-to-convert-char-array-into-string-for-datetime-parse).

Comment: Just use `DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyyMMddHHmmssffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @Evk, thanks for the quick solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0) with your format

From documentation:

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown.

```
var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("202006260718083370", "yyyyMMddHHmmssffff", provider);
```